# Why do wrapper functions need to be returned (decorators in python)

Tags: python, decorator, wrapper

Can someone explain why wrapper functions in decorators need to be returned and also why

```
def decorate(func):
    def wrapper():
        print("Text")
        test_function()

@decorate
def test_function():
  print("More text")

test_function()
```

produces NoneType object is not callable rather than

```
def decorate(func):
    def wrapper():
        print("Text")
        test_function()
    return wrapper

@decorate
def test_function():
    print("More text")

test_function()
```

Comment: Your second code block recurses "forever" (until it hits the interpreter's recursion limit and an exception is raised), because when the `wrapper` function calls `test_function` by name, it's actually calling itself. The original `test_function` gets replaced by the wrapper, thanks to the decorator syntax. If you want to access the original function, you should use the reference that was passed as an argument to the decorator (i.e. `func`). It's also worth noting that you don't *need* to use a wrapper function in a decorator. You can return the same function you were passed if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

```
@decorator
def f():
    ...
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
def f():
    ...
f = decorator(f)
```

So `decorator` must return something for this to make sense, else `f` will be `None`.